# Selecting rows without few values in different columns ( NOT IN )

Tags: mysql, notin

So first of all, I manged to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `trades`
WHERE 15003 NOT IN (`slot1`, `slot2`, `slot3`, `slot4`)
```

And this works correct, gives me rowes without product '15003' in any of those columns.
But what if I don't want to have any of '15003' or '15004' or '15008' those in query?
I want to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `trades`
WHERE 15003 NOT IN (`slot1`, `slot2`, `slot3`, `slot4`) AND
15004 NOT IN (`slot1`, `slot2`, `slot3`, `slot4`) AND
15008 NOT IN (`slot1`, `slot2`, `slot3`, `slot4`)
```

It works, but I think its not proper...

### How can I optimize this?

Edit:
Each trade has its id and 4 slots.

Comment: it really depends on your table structure and what mysql explain states.  what does explain show for this query and the previous?

Comment: Just add EXPLAIN key word before your query and post the result

Comment: CAUTION: Poorly normalized data structure ahead. Expect difficult query syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very poor design choice, exemplified by how much difficulty you're having with this query. Instead of:

```
TABLE trades
  slot1 INT
  slot2 INT
  slot3 INT
  slot4 INT
```

should be properly normalized to something like:

```
TABLE trades
  trade_id INT

TABLE trades_slots
  trade_id INT
  slot_id INT
```

Which will allow you *much* more flexibility and make the queries MUCH easier to write.

```
SELECT *
FROM trades t INNER JOIN trades_slots s
  on t.trade_id = s.trade_id
WHERE s.slot_id NOT IN (15003, 15004, ...)
```

Comment: Hymm.. But it is INT already, not varchars. Do you mean I shouldn't use '' ? It is normalized like this, but I gave it in different form in example.

Comment: I must have been seeing things, I thought there were quotes around your numbers. And if it is normalized like this already then why is your query so broken?

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this:

```
Select *, GROUP_CONCAT(product1,product2,product3,product4) as prods
from Trades
group by ID
having prods not regexp '15003|15004|15008'
```